# clustering with uncertain number of clusters

Tags: clustering

I detect a unmanned aerial vehicle(UAV) in a picture using template matching. The template library only contains targets with different scales, rotations and other differences.I want to simplify the template library using clustering. I learned the k-means and Gaussian mixture model（GMM）but they all need determine the value of k.Are there any approaches which can solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several algorithms allow doing this.
First one is the [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering). When creating your dendrogram, the key is to cut the "longest branches." [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) is also a good alternative. Finally, you can use K-means or GMM and optimize your number of cluster against a metrics (see [sklearn pages on the subject](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation)) (be aware of overfitting)